# IOS: verify if a string is an empty string

Tags: ios, nsstring

is there a method to verify if a NSString haven't characters?
example of string without characters can be:

@"" or @" " or @"\n  " or @"\n\n   ", I want cosider these strings as empty strings and print a nslog that say me that these are emty, what kind of control I should use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this test:

```
if ([[myString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] == 0) {
    // The string is empty
}
```

Comment: +1 I was unaware of this functionality; your answer is better than mine :)

Comment: @WendiKidd Thanks! As a quick offtopic, I have no idea who downvoted your answer, but I think I know why: you are using string constants `@" "` and `@"\n"` instead of character constants `' '` and `'\n'`; fixing this should transform your solution into a fully working one.

Comment: Ah! Silly me, I didn't notice!  Thanks for pointing that out.  I fixed it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through every character in the string and check if it is the space (" ") or newline ("\n") character.  If not, return false.  Else if you search through the whole string and didn't return false, it is "empty".

Something like this:

```
NSString* myStr = @"A STRING";
for(int i = 0; i < [myStr length]; i++)
{
    if(!(([myStr characterAtIndex:i] == @' ') || ([myStr characterAtIndex:i] == @'\n')))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```